# Converted blob to Mp3 but File is unplayable

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, java-io

This is my function for converting blob to mp3:

```
private void convertByyeToMP3(byte[] bytearray,String trackName) {
            try {
                ContextWrapper c = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
                File directory = new File(c.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()
                        + "/Music");
                if (!directory.exists()){
                    directory.mkdir();
                }
                File tempMp3 = File.createTempFile(trackName, ".mp3",
                        directory);
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempMp3);
                fos.write(bytearray);
                fos.close();
                Log.d("Byte array to mp3 conversion: ", "successfull");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.d("In convertToByteToMp3 Function:", ex.toString());
            }
        }
```

When I execute this function ,I can see the created mp3 files in my app folder but when I try to play them Using my own code or using ES File Explorer, they both can't play it.

This is the function I use play my music:

```
private MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    private void playSong(String songPath) {
        try {
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(songPath);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

And I use this sample code to play the track:

```
ContextWrapper c = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        File directory = new File(c.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/Music");
        playSong(directory.getPath() + File.separator + "kurchina");
```

This is where I read database and send the blob:

```
cursor = mDbHelper.GetTables();
            byte[] blob = null;
            DATAS data = new DATAS();
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                blob = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("data"));
                if (blob != null) {convertByyeToMP3(blob,data_MusicName);}
                db.addDATAS(data);
            }
```

FYIs: 
  -Read and Write permissions added to manifest. 
  -Path and filename are check and they exist 
  -blob byte is not corrupted

Comment: How are you obtaining / generating the byte array that you are writing? How do you know it is not corrupted? Your method implies that you want to "convert" some kind of data to MP3 data, but I see no "conversions" taking place. What is the nature of this data?

Comment: That still doesn't give anything about the nature of the data. How did the data get into the database? Where did it come from? *How do you know the data you originally stored in the database is not corrupted?* For all we know you just put random strings of bytes in your database.

Answer (score 1):

There are all sorts of things that might have gone wrong, either in the code that you have shown us or elsewhere.  So you need to do your own troubleshooting.  Methodically.

1. Figure out if the problem is with the song file you have extracted or the way you are playing it.  For example, try to play the extracted file using a free-standing mp3 player utility.
2. Assuming that the problem is the extracted file, the next thing is to figure out if the file is the same as the one that you originally inserted into the database.  Compare the file sizes and the checksums using the relevant external applications.

and so on.

Comment: thanks. found the problem. its about permissions. I explain it on my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. 
It didn't play because the music files were stored in my app folder which is only accessible using a rooted device. 
When I copied the music to my sdcard they played well, but in my app folder using rooted nexus 7 I couldn't play it even with an mp3-player app.